# UI is not updating from other application data in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

My Class relation is like this Model:

```
Class MainModel

{

data  data1 = new data();

public override string LFE
    {
        get { return data1.lnf.ToString(); }
        set { data1.lnf = Convert.ToByte(value); }
    }


public override UInt16 GetRsBValue(int index)
    {

        return (byte)this.data1.CConfig[index].Bline;
    }

public override void SetRsBValue(UInt16 value, int index)
    {
        byte[] arr = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
        this.data1.CConfig[index].Bline = arr[0];
    }

}

Class data

{

public byte Bline
{
    get { return this.bline; }
    set { this.bline = value; }
}

public byte lnf
    {
        get { return this.ln_frequency; }
        set { this.ln_frequency = value; }
    }

}

Class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChange

{

public UInt16 Rschange
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eObj.GetRsBValue(this.index);
        }
        set
        {
                this.eObj.SetRsBValue(value, this.Index);
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Rschange"));
                this.eObj.writedata(DefaultFileName);
        }
    } 

 public string LF
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eObj.LFE;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eObj.LFE = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(" LF"));
        }
    }

}
```

In Model side I have created instance of data class in main Model.
I'm getting data from other application to my application. I'm getting that updated value till data class but it's not showing that value in `MainModel`. So It's not updating mu UI at all. Please tell me how can I update my UI when I'm getting value from other application.

P.S: I don't want to create Model class instance in `ViewModel` side and I have 10 properties and 10 method like this in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your call to property changed in your LF property.

```
 // note the extra space                              V
 this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(" LF"));
```

If you create your property changed handler like this:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
  var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
  if (handler != null)
  {
    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

You can prevent such typos by using the following syntax:

```
public string LF
{
    get
    {
        return this.eObj.LFE;
    }
    set
    {
        this.eObj.LFE = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for typo here. Can you tell me by doing this my UI will get update after getting value from other application. I'm using serail communication for sending and receving data. After receving data from other application I have to update my UI please tell me how can I achieve this.

Comment: If you `set` your data through your `ViewModel`, it will work. I you somehow change your Model/data, you will need to find a way to notify your ViewModel of this. You can call a function or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your data as well and listen to that.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code for me where I can do this the way you suggested. I have tried with INotificationPropertychanged in Class mainModelbut that's not working for me. One more thing I have some method where I'm getting updated value where I cann't use this INotificationProprtychanged . Please tell me how can I achieve this.